# AngularJS Methods attached to the scope vs within the scope of the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting to re-factor the project we have been working on for a couple of months. There has been a lot learned about Angular along the way, and many of this will be implemented in the re-factoring.

During this process I am noticing a lot of methods attached to the `$scope` of, say, a controller. Some of which aren't actually called by anything in the `view` or watched, or for that matter doing anything else other than fire and forget.

So it got me to thinking. If a method is not required by any views, or having its result watched would there be any performance gains by not attaching these methods to the `$scope`?

For example, Lets say, in a controller, I am asynchronously saving some data - fire and forget sort of stuff.

Would this:

```
saveState();    
function saveState(){
       // do my saving here. don't need to return anything
}
```

Give me any performance gains over this:

```
$scope.saveState();    
$scope.saveState = function(){
     // do my saving here. don't need to return anything
}
```

Comment: Im just guessing now, and i guess that angular doesn't bother with the  internal functions of the controller, but may do some processing regarding functions attached to scope.

Comment: So really, functions attached to the scope, that don't need to be, are taking processing away from those that DO need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just discovered something very true.  I would actually say it is bad to do that because cause you are polluting the scope.  $scope should only have properties on it that directly need to be used by a view.  You may not notice the performance gains with smaller apps but when you get into the 50+ controller range with thousands of data points in scope, ever little bit can help.  I did a little write up at Coderwall (https://coderwall.com/p/nsanaa?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Abreck421&t%5B%5D=breck421) about js profiling with flame chart.  It may help you put some numbers to your conclusions.

I took your thoughts a step further and created a init load model for my controllers.

```
MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var self = this;

    this.init = function () {
        this.setScope();
        this.load();
    };

    this.load = function () {
        this.setScopeEvents();
    };

    this.setScope = function () {
        $scope.isLovingStackOverflow = true;
    };

    this.setScopeEvents = function () {
        $scope.answerQuestion = function() { /* answer a question */}
    };

    this.init();
}]);
```

The beauty with this is that you can call any of the this.* functions from unit tests.

I want to commend you on your thought process change.  There are many more in your near future with Angular :)

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Looks good :) Thank you. So a good rule of thumb then; if it's not used by the view or being watched then don't attach it to the scope?

Comment: You are welcome and you got it.  There is just no need for it to be in scope.

Comment: Do you know, or have you tested to see if there is there much actual impact on performance? I can imagine with only a handful of methods on scopes it might not matter, though with many it might

Comment: I would not expect that pulling a handful of items out of scope would be noticeable like you said.  My latest project had performance issues and scope bloat reduction was one of our needed tasks.  We actually conversed with Brad Green and Igor Minar about our issues.  After that it just became a best practice for us to keep scope properties limited whats needed for the view.  Not to mention you are making it clear what is and what is not needed in scope for the rest of your team.  Also note that the scope changes were NOT the game changers for our performance issues, but it helped.

Comment: self = this allows the saving of the scope at that point in code.  it allows you to call this.whatever by using self.whatever when you cannot access the needed scope.